# Why is a NullPointerException thrown on my @PersistenceContext EntityManager?

Tags: java, spring, entitymanager

I have been trying to use the @PersistenceContext annotation to inject an EntityManager into my Spring app. However, a NullPointerException is thrown when I try to call one of its methods, leading me to believe that it is not being injected for some reason. I'm sure I got this to work in a different project, but I don't have access to that project to know what has changed.

**Note:** Most of the solutions I've seen mention @EJB or @Stateless but I didn't use those in my working project.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dao.CustomerDaoJpaImpl.createCustomer(CustomerDaoJpaImpl.java:41)
    at boot.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:43)
```

MainClass.java:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ICustomerDao customerDao = new CustomerDaoJpaImpl();
        customerDao.createCustomer("john@email.com", "John", "Doe");
    }
}
```

CustomerDaoJpaImpl.java:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CustomerDaoJpaImpl implements ICustomerDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Customer createCustomer(String email, String firstName, String lastName) {
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        Customer customer = new Customer(email, firstName, lastName);
        entityManager.persist(customer);
        transaction.commit();
        return customer;
    }
}
```

WebMvcConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "dao", "service", "controller", "com.nkosi.example" })
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("critter-tourney");
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager getTransactionBean() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(getEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="critter-tourney">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/critter_tourney"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*"/>        
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
        </properties>       
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nkosi.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>critter-tourney</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>critter-tourney Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.groupId>org.springframework</spring.groupId>
        <spring.version>5.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${spring.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${spring.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${spring.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${spring.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${spring.groupId}.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>critter-tourney</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You need to initialize the Spring context somehow first.

Comment: When `new` keyword is used to create `customerDao` instance , it is not a spring managed bean . The autowiring of `entityManager` will not happen in that case and NPE is expected.

Answer (score 1):

When you create object like this with new operation, it's just normal class.

```
ICustomerDao customerDao = new CustomerDaoJpaImpl();
```

There wont be any dependency injection nor any `PersistenceContext`. Thus your `entityManager` is null.

You need to get Bean from Application context something like this.

**Note:** This is sample code just for reference, it may or may not work. As Bean Name can be something else.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MainClass.class);

         BeanFactory factory = context;
        ICustomerDao  customerDao = (CustomerDaoJpaImpl) factory.getBean("customerDaoJpaImpl");
        customerDao.createCustomer("john@email.com", "John", "Doe");

}
```